# How do I configure a fingerprint scanner?

Tags: 11.04, hardware, authentication

I have a HP dv6-3079tx.

One feature I like about it is the fingerprint scanner,

Is there a utility out there that will allow me to swipe my finger whenever I am required to enter my password?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on the model of the fingerprint scanner in your machine.  You'll want to look at either [bioapi-linux](http://code.google.com/p/bioapi-linux/) and [pam-bioapi](http://code.google.com/p/pam-bioapi/) or the [fprint project](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/fprint).  They seem to have support for different hardware, and only fprint is in the Ubuntu repositories.  There are directions as of Jaunty here: [HOWTO: Fingerprint reading in Ubuntu with fprint](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=760018).

Answer (score 1):

Also, if you own a Lenovo ThinkPad, you might want to look at the corresponding [ThinkWiki](http://www.thinkwiki.org/wiki/Integrated_Fingerprint_Reader) page for a little bit more device specific information.